# Is there a way to load webpack bundle using requirejs require function?

Tags: webpack, requirejs

I want to load a webpack bundle using requirejs require function. The webpack bundle file is loading and its global variables/objects are available on page (if access using devtool console), but the requirejs callback function is not getting called.

```
// module structure that bundled with webpack
(function() {
  var module = { /* module code */ }

  define('MODULE_NAME', module);
})();

// code to load webpack bundle
var modules = ['MODULE_NAME'];
reqObject.bundles['PATH_TO_WEBPACK_BUNDLE'] = modules;

require(modules, function () {
  // NOT BEING CALLED
});

requirejs.onError = function() { debugger; }
```

If requirejs callback called, I can run app bootstrapping code in it. Also the RequireJS onError handler is not getting called to show any error.

Answer (score 0):

Added following configuration to output bundle as global module

output: {
  library: undefined,
  libraryTarget: 'global'
}